# How to get data from an item in a recyclerView and view it in a different activity on editTexts

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When the user logins an activity where the user can create their account opens (CreateProfileActivity). When the profile is created the user is redirected to the recyclerView activity where their profile info is displayed in a recyclerView. When user clicks on the item in recyclerView the Update Activity will open. I want their profile information from the recyclerView to load on the Update Activity. Please help.

P.S. Since I haven't made the CreateProfile_Activity open only once, as I don't want the user to create more than one profile, So for now: I ran the app once and created an account and then I changed it so now when the user logins it opens the recyclerView_Activity.

Here is the recyclerView_Activity

```
package com.example.insert_update_activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class recyclerView_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

   // Button insertBtn;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DBHelper myDB;
    ArrayList<String> temp_id, temp_name, temp_age;
    myAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
 /*       insertBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insertBtn);

        insertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(recyclerView_Activity.this, Insert_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });*/

        myDB = new DBHelper(recyclerView_Activity.this);

        temp_id = new ArrayList<>();
        temp_name = new ArrayList<>();
        temp_age = new ArrayList<>();

        storeDataInArrays();

        myAdapter = new myAdapter(recyclerView_Activity.this, this, temp_id, temp_name, temp_age);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView_Activity.this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1)
        {
            recreate();
        }
    }

    void storeDataInArrays() {
        Cursor cursor = myDB.readData();  // Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();

        if (cursor.getCount() == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(recyclerView_Activity.this, "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                temp_id.add(cursor.getString(0));
                temp_name.add(cursor.getString(1));
                temp_age.add(cursor.getString(2));


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the UpdateActivity

```
package com.example.insert_update_activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Update_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name, age;
    Button updateBtn;
    String id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
        age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_age);
        updateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateBtn);

        updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String sName = name.getText().toString().trim();
                String sAge = age.getText().toString().trim();
                DBHelper db = new DBHelper(Update_Activity.this);

                db.updateData(id, sName, sAge);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Update_Activity.this, com.example.insert_update_activity.recyclerView_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        getAndSetIntentData();

    }

    void getAndSetIntentData() {
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("id") && getIntent().hasExtra("Name") && getIntent().hasExtra("Age"))
        {
            // Getting data from Intent
            id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
            String NAME = getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");
            String AGE = getIntent().getStringExtra("Age");

            // Setting Intent Data
            name.setText(NAME);
            age.setText(AGE);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(Update_Activity.this, "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the DBHelper

```
package com.example.insert_update_activity;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Database.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Create table
    private static final String TABLE_TEMP = "TEMPP";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COLUMN_AGE = "age";

    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String profileQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEMP +
                " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_AGE + " INTEGER " + ")";
        db.execSQL(profileQuery);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TEMP);
        onCreate(db);


    }

    // Functions for TEMP TABLE ********************************************************************************************************************************************  PROFILE TEMP
    public Boolean insertData(String name, String age) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_AGE, age);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_TEMP, null, cv);

        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Insert", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return  false;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Data Inserted Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    }

    Cursor readData() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TEMP;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;

        if (db != null) {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    // Update data using where clause;
    public Boolean updateData(String row_id, String name, String age)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_AGE, age);

        long result = db.update(TABLE_TEMP, cv, COLUMN_ID + " =? ", new String[]{row_id});
       
        if (result == -1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Update",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Updated!",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

    }


}
```

Here is the Adapter

```
package com.example.insert_update_activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    Activity activity;
    private ArrayList id, name, age;

    myAdapter(Activity activity, Context context, ArrayList id, ArrayList name, ArrayList age) {

        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;

    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.id_txt.setText(String.valueOf(id.get(position)));
        holder.name_txt.setText(String.valueOf(name.get(position)));
        holder.age_txt.setText(String.valueOf(age.get(position)));
        holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Update_Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(id.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("name", String.valueOf(name.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("age", String.valueOf(age.get(position)));
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return id.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView id_txt, name_txt, age_txt;
        LinearLayout mainLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            id_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_txt);
            name_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
            age_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.age_txt);
            mainLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        }
    }
}
```

And here is the xml file my_row for the recyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#000000"
        app:cardElevation="3dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#9A9797"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameTitle"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="NAME:"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ageTitle"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AGE:"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/nameTitle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nameTitle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nameTitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/age_txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Age"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ageTitle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTitle" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The login activity is pretty simple. It just allows the user to login if username == "User1" and password == "123456".
The CreateProfile_Activity just uses the insertData once

Answer (score 0):

Okay so now it works. I'm not sure this is why, but I will post the changes I made.

So one problem was in myAdapter. In the mainLayout OnClick the "name" and "age" where different from the "Name" and "Age" in the UpdateActivity where I get data from Intent. The first letters of both 'age' and 'name' were not in CAPITALS.
Another thing I changed was the get(position) in the onBindHolder.

Now the onBindHolder looks like this:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.id_txt.setText(String.valueOf(id.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())));
    holder.name_txt.setText(String.valueOf(name.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())));
    holder.age_txt.setText(String.valueOf(age.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())));


    holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Update_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(id.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())));
            intent.putExtra("Name", String.valueOf(name.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())));
            intent.putExtra("Age", String.valueOf(age.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())));
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            //activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });

}
```

Hope it helps anyone